# @GrpcAdvice does not handle the @GRpcService exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, grpc

In gRPC with Spring Boot, I expect for `@GRpcService` with the help of `@GrpcAdvice` and  `@GrpcExceptionHandler` the exceptions be handled. But the exception couldn't be sent to the ExceptionHandlers class.

Needs for extra configuration?

```
@GRpcService
public class GrpcServer extends MicroServiceGrpc.MicroServiceImplBase {
    @Override
    public void generalCall(RequestPr request, StreamObserver<ResponsePr> observer)  {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

@GrpcAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlers {
    @GrpcExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public Status serviceException(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I found , for @GRpcService the correct package is **net.devh.boot.grpc.server.service.GrpcService**, I was using the wrong one : **org.lognet.springboot.grpc.GRpcService**